# Why Do I Get "Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v7/recyclerview/extensions/ListAdapter"

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-architecture-components, android-architecture-lifecycle

I get the dreaded `java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex` error. The stack trace shows the root cause as:

```
Caused by: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v7/recyclerview/extensions/ListAdapter;
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:661)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:616)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:598)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:198)
        at com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerCallable.call(DexArchiveMergerCallable.java:61)
```

What is the root cause?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Most likely, you are attempting to use these two dependencies:

```
implementation "android.arch.paging:runtime:1.0.0-alpha5"
implementation "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.0"
```

The conflicting class (`android.support.v7.recyclerview.extensions.ListAdapter`) moved to `recyclerview-v7` from the Paging `runtime`... but only with `1.0.0-alpha6` or higher of the Paging `runtime`. With `1.0.0-alpha5`, coupled with `27.1.0` of the Support Library, you get the same class in both places.

Instead, migrate to:

```
implementation "android.arch.paging:runtime:1.0.0-alpha6"
implementation "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.0"
```

Comment: I spent a good minute puzzled as to how you answered so fast.... It took me a second

Comment: @BenMohorc: Yeah, sometimes, after solving a problem, I write up a question-and-answer pair. Mostly, to help others. Partially, in case I run into it again and forget what the solution was, so that I find my own answer in a search. Future Me has been grateful for Past Me's answers from time to time... :-)

Comment: I've updated the recyclerview to 27.1.0 and I'm still getting the same issue.  Any suggestions?

Comment: @Brandon: Did you update `android.arch.paging:runtime` to `1.0.0-alpha6`?

Comment: @CommonsWare Turns out I just waited a couple days and the dependencies resolved themselves!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar but different error message, and there seems no other suspicious gradle dependencies which may collide with `implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'`

> Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v7/widget/DefaultItemAnimator$6;

Finnally, I found that there was already a file `android-support-v7-recyclerview.jar` existing in the lib directory of this project.

Remove this file and sync with gradle, then everything went fine