# Multidex enabled - still unable to merge dex

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, kotlin, android-multidex

this is my build.gradle

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 27
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "xxxx.xxxx.xxxx"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

this is my Manifest.xml

```
 <application
    android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
.../>
```

these are my dependencies

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')


    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.0'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.8.0'
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.8.0"
    implementation 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4.4'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko:0.10.4"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-design:0.10.4"

    //    CircleImage
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    //    Glide
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.5.0'
    //DateTimePicker
    implementation 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:3.4.0'

    implementation 'org.ocpsoft.prettytime:prettytime:4.0.1.Final'


    implementation 'com.github.kittinunf.fuel:fuel-android:1.12.0'


    implementation 'com.seatgeek:placesautocomplete:0.3-SNAPSHOT'



    implementation project(path: ':regservice')
}
```

still gradle build fails because of

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex

can someone please figure out why?
I am 2 days into this problem and I still have no solution

```
 Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:100)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:63)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:88)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:241)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:230)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:124)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:80)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:105)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:99)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:625)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:580)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:99)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
```

Comment: have you tried clean & rebuild?

Comment: Look in the Gradle Console for a full Java stack trace associated with this build error. If you see one, it should have more details in it of specifically what is going wrong. If you do not see one, try a command-line build where you include `--stacktrace` to force the stack trace to appear. See [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49076888/115145) for an example of what I am referring to.

Comment: Show full error

Comment: for API 21+ there is no need to add multidex lib as dependency and no need to extend your app from android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication, that line in buildConfig is enough :  https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html#avoid

Comment: check your manifest file, any activity or permission added in two times

Comment: added stacktrace

Comment: no permission twice in manifest

Comment: have you added any library? if added, remove and build

Comment: implementation project(path: ':regservice') this one is problem, remove this and build

Comment: removed both. still no change

Comment: did you add application class in the manifest?

Comment: as you see in the second code block in my question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to merge dex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46267621/unable-to-merge-dex)

Comment: Try to change the play service version

Comment: i went down to 11.4.2 but nothing changed

Comment: what is your android studio version?

Answer (score 0):

Create application class like,

```
  public class MyApplication extends Application {
  @Override
   protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
      super.attachBaseContext(base);
      MultiDex.install(this);
   }
  }
```

use "MyApplication" instead of android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication

```
<application
android:name=".MyApplication"
 />
```

Comment: unfortunately not